# What's the exact meaning of this sentence "Now, I can patch us in over here, the landing pad."?

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is a fighting scene of the movie "Rogue One."

> "They've closed the shield gate. We're stuck here. But the rebel fleet are pulling in. We just have to get a signal strong enough to get through to them... and let them know that we're trapped down here. For that, we have to connect to the communications tower. ***Now, I can patch us in over here, the landing pad.*** ~..." (*He have a extension cable to connect.)

I don't see well what the sentence means. especially "***patch us in over here,***"

patch us (in over here)? Or patch (us in over here)?...

How is he going to do exactly?

Comment: "Patch in" means to connect to the system; connect your equipment to the system's equipment so data or communications can be passed.  It might involve plugging in a connector or fastening wires.  "Patch us in over here": "over here" is the location that the connection is desired.

Comment: **Patching in** implies a temporary connection, in the same way as a patch on an item of clothing is a makeshift repair. The verb definition here refers to the computer/telecoms meaning. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patch

Comment: I can understand why some are voting to close, but I think this meaning might be hard to pick up on, given the [30+ definitions for _patch_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/patch). JS Kim, you might want to read through this [Details, Please meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for some tips on asking your next question – had you explained what you already found when you looked up _patch_ in a dictionary, I think most of these close votes might have been warded off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, when they say "patching in", they are implying a temporary connection in the sense of a telecoms/computer sense. In this section of the movie, they are basically ringing (or calling; patching in) to the people on the landing pad.

(let me know if you need more clarification)